# Count character in specific cell and add that character a specified amount of times

Tags: r, linux

I am working on 16s data and try to format an OTU table to upload it to a different tool.

Here is my TSV table:

[image: My tsv table looks like this]

It is supposed to look like this:

[image: but it is supposed to look like that]

So I need R to count the number of semicolons ";" in each cell in column "taxonomy" and if the number is smaller than 6 I need R to add the required number of semincolons to make it six semicolons per cell.
I am new to the bioinformatics field so any help would be much appreciated!

I tried

```
ifelse(str_count(ASV$taxonomy, ";") >= 6, ASV$taxonomy, paste0(ASV$taxonomy, " ;"))
```

But I don´t know how I can tell R to add so many semicolons that it makes 6 semicolons in each cell.

Thank you in advance,
Lea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't have your dataset, I just made an example dataframe.

Next time when you ask, make sure you don't post image of codes/dataset, you should use `dput(your_data)` and paste the result in the question.

### Input

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

df <- tibble(Name = LETTERS[1:4], 
             OTU = c("A;", "A; B;", "A; B; C; D; E; F;", "A; B; C; D; E;"))


df
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Name  OTU              
  <chr> <chr>            
1 A     A;               
2 B     A; B;            
3 C     A; B; C; D; E; F;
4 D     A; B; C; D; E;
```

### Code and output

First count the number of ";" in the column, if it's fewer than 6, add some more at the end of the string in `OTU`. If it is not fewer than 6, use the original `OTU` value.

This will entirely replace the original `OTU` column.

```
df %>% mutate(OTU = ifelse(str_count(OTU, ";") < 6, 
                           paste(OTU, str_dup("; ", 6 - str_count(OTU, ";"))), 
                           OTU))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Name  OTU                
  <chr> <chr>              
1 A     "A; ; ; ; ; ; "    
2 B     "A; B; ; ; ; ; "   
3 C     "A; B; C; D; E; F;"
4 D     "A; B; C; D; E; ; "
```

Comment: Thank you, for the quick and helpful response!
I will use the command for showing codes and datasets the next time! :)

Answer (score 1):

We could use `separate` with the `fill` argument from `tidyr` package and
then paste them all together and finally replace `NA` by `""`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  separate(col1, c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g"), fill = "right", sep = ";") %>% 
  mutate(col1 = paste(a,b,c,d,e,f,g, sep = "; "), .keep="unused") %>% 
  mutate(col1 = str_replace_all(col1, "NA", ""))
```

```
   col1                                                                                                     
   <chr>                                                                                                    
 1 "Bacteria;  Proteobacteria;  Gammaproteobacteria; ; ; ; "                                                
 2 "Bacteria;  Proteobacteria;  Gammaproteobacteria; ; ; ; "                                                
 3 "Bacteria;  Actinobacteria;  Rubrobacteria;  Rubrobacterales;  Rubrobacteraceae;  Rubrobacter; "         
 4 "Bacteria;  Gemmatimonadetes;  Gemm-1; ; ; ; "                                                           
 5 "Bacteria;  Proteobacteria;  Gammaproteobacteria;  Chromatiales; ; ; "                                   
 6 "Bacteria;  Actinobacteria;  Nitriliruptoria;  Nitriliruptorales;  Nitriliruptoraceae; ; "               
 7 "Bacteria;  Proteobacteria;  Gammaproteobacteria;  Chromatiales; ; ; "                                   
 8 "Bacteria;  Actinobacteria;  Thermoleophilia;  Solirubrobacterales; ; ; "                                
 9 "Bacteria;  Proteobacteria;  Gammaproteobacteria;  Chromatiales; ; ; "                                   
10 "Bacteria;  Proteobacteria;  Alphaproteobacteria;  Sphingomonadales;  Sphingomonadaceae;  Kaistobacter; "
11 "Bacteria;  Actinobacteria;  Thermoleophilia;  Solirubrobacterales; ; ; "                                
12 "Bacteria;  Proteobacteria;  Betaproteobacteria;  Burkholderiales;  Oxalobacteraceae;  Ralstonia; "      
13 "Bacteria;  Actinobacteria;  Actinobacteria;  Actinomycetales;  Pseudonocardiaceae; ; "                  
14 "Bacteria;  Actinobacteria;  Actinobacteria;  Actinomycetales;  Micrococcaceae;  Arthrobacter; "
```

data:

```
structure(list(col1 = c("Bacteria; Proteobacteria; Gammaproteobacteria;", 
"Bacteria; Proteobacteria; Gammaproteobacteria;", "Bacteria; Actinobacteria; Rubrobacteria; Rubrobacterales; Rubrobacteraceae; Rubrobacter;", 
"Bacteria; Gemmatimonadetes; Gemm-1;", "Bacteria; Proteobacteria; Gammaproteobacteria; Chromatiales;", 
"Bacteria; Actinobacteria; Nitriliruptoria; Nitriliruptorales; Nitriliruptoraceae;", 
"Bacteria; Proteobacteria; Gammaproteobacteria; Chromatiales;", 
"Bacteria; Actinobacteria; Thermoleophilia; Solirubrobacterales;", 
"Bacteria; Proteobacteria; Gammaproteobacteria; Chromatiales;", 
"Bacteria; Proteobacteria; Alphaproteobacteria; Sphingomonadales; Sphingomonadaceae; Kaistobacter;", 
"Bacteria; Actinobacteria; Thermoleophilia; Solirubrobacterales;", 
"Bacteria; Proteobacteria; Betaproteobacteria; Burkholderiales; Oxalobacteraceae; Ralstonia;", 
"Bacteria; Actinobacteria; Actinobacteria; Actinomycetales; Pseudonocardiaceae;", 
"Bacteria; Actinobacteria; Actinobacteria; Actinomycetales; Micrococcaceae; Arthrobacter;"
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```